# How do I make Firefox spellcheck in multiple languages simultaneously?

Tags: firefox, language, spell-check

I want Firefox to assume that text may be in a mixture of languages and words should be looked up in multiple dictionaries. (For example, everything in en-GB, en-US, ru, be and be-classic should be consider as good, everything else should be underlined and corrections from all dictionaries should be offered). Is there an add-on for "multi-language spell-check"?

Alternatively, can I merge all dictionaries into one big combined dictionary?

Comment: What Operating System are you on ?

Comment: GNU/Linux Debian (mostly squeeze)

Comment: I also wish Firefox could do this. Not strictly an "answer," but you could try using Chrome, which does support multiple-language spell checking out of the box: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95604.

Answer (score 29):

I use French and English in almost all of my emails and this is a nightmare.

There is a (quite simple) solution, but you need to hack one of your dictionaries: copy-paste the content of e.g. your English dictionary into your French one; it works! As simple as that!

This is how I solved this issue on Mac OS X:

1. Go to `/Users/HERE_YOUR_USER/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles` (use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> if your Library folder is hidden), and select your profile folder (mine was `default.uo0`) and the extensions folder.
2. You will see folders for each of your dictionaries (`en-US@dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org`  and `fr-classique-reforme1990@dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org` in my case). In each main folder, a `dictionaries` folder.
3. Copy the content of the .aff and .dic of one of your dictionaries into the `.aff` and `.dic` file of the other. **Don't copy the first line in the `.dic` file; it's the word count!**

**Warning:** in the `.dic` file, update the word count on the first line. It must be the number of lines of the file minus 1 (the first which is the word count).

4. Restart Firefox! And now, vous pouvez taper en français et in English in the same text area!

Comment: Just did a `cp extensions/en-gb@flyingtophat.co.uk/dictionaries/* extensions/pt-BR@dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org/dictionaries/` here. Didn't seem to work very well. How did you join the files exactly?

Comment: I had English and Ukrainian dictionaries (in this order). When I copied Ukrainian into English, it didn't work at all. But when I copied English into Ukrainian, it worked but I needed to remove `SET ISO8859-1` before `en-gb.aff`, otherwise plurals and other forms would be marked.

Comment: Bizarre, these dictionary folders are not in my profile folder...

Comment: @François Thanks! That's an elegant solution. Do you have to do this over and over again with every update of Firefox?

Comment: @IIya nope, the dictionary is still bilingual after several Firefox updates. But don't update your dictionary ;)

Comment: On Linux it uses dictionaries from `/usr/share/hunspell`. I changed `spellchecker.dictionary_path` in about:config it worked to `/home/me/somefolder` and put the merged .dic/.aff in there, so I didn't have to make a system-wide change (or have the files overwritten by updates)

Comment: This solution does not longer work straight forward, because the dictionaries are now typically part of language pack extensions, and stored as `.xpi` files.

Answer (score 9):

Seems like Firefox 100 can support spellchecking multiple languages natively.

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/100.0/releasenotes/

> Firefox spell checking now checks spelling in multiple languages. To enable additional languages, select them in the text field’s context menu.

Comment: It is not working reliably. Some combination of languages mess everything up. For example, when I use British ENG + Ukrainian British text never gets checked. But with US + Ukrainian it works... Also British + Russian works fine.... Its a freaking mess...

Comment: Actually no. I just checked. Ukrainian breaks both US and British. But not Russian… Russian does not break English............ This is extremely frustrating!

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer Is it [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1772762)? If so, you are invited to vote for it (or comment, if votes are not supported).

Comment: It seems that you need to set multiple dictionaries for each site on its own. Is there a setting somewhere to set it up as default for all sites?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is an easy solution to this. I use two different languages on a daily basis and the best (not ideal) solution is a combination of multiple dictionaries and an add on such as:

[Dictionary Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3414)
or
[Quick Locale Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1333)

Both of which present their own problems.

Another, less than ideal solution, is:

[ImTranslator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2257/)

Whilst it is a translator, it also supports multilingual spell checking.

Comment: Here's a current link to Quick Locale Switcher: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-locale-switcher2/

Doesn't seem to be any faster than clicking the text field though.

Comment: links outdated.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks François; this was inspiring. The corresponding solution in Ubuntu/Linux does the same for the hunspell. I wanted to combine my English dictionary with Hebrew, and I did this:

```
cd /usr/share/hunspell
sudo cp he.dic he.dic.bak
sudo cp he.aff he.aff.bak
sudo sh -c 'cat en_US.dic >> he.dic'
sudo sh -c 'cat en_US.aff >> he.aff'
```

(The `sh -c` is required since the append, `>>`, operation needs sudo privileges also). And of course fix the number of lines on the top of the .dic file like you said (count the lines using `wc -l he.dic`.

Comment: What is *"hunspell"*?

Answer (score 5):

*Somewhat embarrassingly, I mixed up Thunderbird and Firefox. The method should work equally for both though, except that the firefox profiles are stored in `~/.mozilla/firefox`, not `~/.thunderbird`.*

---

As of writing, most answers don't work straight forward or at all anymore. The closest is the recommendation to add content to `persdict.dat`, but the [answer of Dolanor](https://superuser.com/a/1117490/191663) doesn't work straight forward with modern versions of spell checkers, because the dictionary files typically don't contain all variants of the words -- but rather rules how to form them from a dictionary of base forms.

What I did instead was to use the command

```
unmunch /usr/share/hunspell/en_US.{dic,aff}
```

to generate a list of all variants and append *that* to `$HOME/.thunderbird/<PROFILEFOLDER>/persdict.dat`. This should work for any language; In my case I am using a German dictionary in thunderbird, with `en_US` added to the `persdict.dat` file.

### Limitations

While this works *in principle*, there *will* remain cases that are not handled well due to rules that go beyond the forming of the words.

With a German main dictionary and an English generated `persdict.dat` in particular, the spell checker will complain about constructs like hyphenated English words.

As pointed out by [jbrock's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/108177/how-do-i-make-firefox-spellcheck-in-multiple-languages-simultaneously/1619504?noredirect=1#comment2579904_1619504), this setting also doesn't  account for the possibility of English words being capitalized (e.g. title case style). They provided a solution in [the comment](https://superuser.com/questions/108177/how-do-i-make-firefox-spellcheck-in-multiple-languages-simultaneously/1619504?noredirect=1#comment2579904_1619504).

Comment: I really appreciate this answer. I noticed after following the steps that the words which start with capital letters were being marked. I therefore ran this to have a version for each word that starts with a capital letter. `while read -r l; do var="$var $l ${l^}"; done < persdict.dat; echo "$var" | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '!NF || !seen[$0]++' | sed '1d' > new-persdict.dat`. This command takes a while. Here is my generated persdict.dat file for en_US. https://brockcochran.com/1/persdict.dat

Answer (score 2):

Thanks fidlr, this was inspiring. ;)

I wanted to do the same without using root rights for that.
So I based my work on you and came to use the personal dictionary:
**Warning, my personal dictionary was empty, it will surely destroy yours if you have some data in here.**

```
cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/
nbLines=$(wc -l < /usr/share/hunspell/fr_FR.dic)
cut -d/ -f1 /usr/share/hunspell/fr_FR.dic | tail -$(( --nbLines )) >> ./persdict.dat
```

I remove the first line of the dictionary, because it's the number of dictionary entries in the .dic file.

Comment: This is the only answer, that still works directly in Thunderbird 78.x. However, more processing may be needed; The `persdict.dat` file is "dumb" and lines are interpreted directly as words. By contrast, hunspell dictionaries contains flags separated by `/`, which need to be stripped, and different grammatical forms have to be generated. In my case I added the English dictionary to `persdict.dat`, and had to add plural variants and title-case variants separately.

Comment: Also, for skipping the first lines it is easier to just use `tail -n +2`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack that sort of works using the Firefox user dictionary.

You can manually add individual words to your personal user dictionary which will then not be marked as typos. You can also edit the file for it ('persdict.dat' within your Firefox profile folder) and add LOTS of words to it. I downloaded a dictionary list for my second language with 400k words and just paste it in the .dat file, which is essentially a text file you can open with any editor.

Now I can type in two languages without annoying spell check underlines.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying dictionary no loner works (dictionaries are elsewhere than specified in answers and are signed, so no modification is possible).
It is possible to add entries to `persdict.dat` - words that you add manually go there.
To generate all possible words in polish on Linux close Firefox and use following command:

```
unmunch /usr/share/hunspell/pl_PL.{dic,aff} 2>/dev/null \
 | iconv -f iso-8859-2 -t utf-8 \
 > /home/mateuszzz/.mozilla/firefox/z2d3veoq.default-release/persdict.dat
```

I determined input encoding with program `enca`.

This still isn't full solution, as Capitalized variants of words are not generated and still treated as errors ("dobrze" is recognized as correct, "Dobrze" at beginning of sentence is not).

Warning: it is important to close Firefox before running this command.

Answer (score 0):

I found one very small and underrated addon to solve this porblem: [Automatic Spelling Language](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/automatic-spelling-language/)

It solves it at 90%, as it switches to language that has most symbols, not counting the white-spaces. For the most of the use cases this hould suffice. IDK why Mozilla can't just inject it to be the native part of browser, instead of making "multilingual" spellchecking that does not work at all.

Don't forget to delete your `content-prefs.sqlite` file!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm not sure that bot hint inviting to make edits is relevant, but the deletion of `content-prefs.sqlite` should indeed be elaborated - why the file needs to be deleted?