# How to have multiple proofing languages in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

In Firefox,
I'd like to have multiple, or at least two, proofing languages and keep English as main display language. For instance, and as I'm French, the following screenshot of web WhatsApp shows that Firefox corrects my English sentences well but that doesn't work for my native language. I didn't find anything on the net or Firefox's preferences. Maybe this goes with an add-on?

[image]

I also have the exact same question for Thunderbird Mail, should I open another question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make Firefox spellcheck in multiple languages simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/108177/how-do-i-make-firefox-spellcheck-in-multiple-languages-simultaneously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a French Dictionary or a dictionary for any language here

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/

Then you can change the language of the spell checker using the context menu

[image: Firefox Language Menu]

Edit: You can try this extension [Automatic Spelling Language](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/automatic-spelling-language/)

Github [Repo](https://github.com/kimsey0/FirefoxAutoDict)

Comment: Thanks! That's a good answer, it helps. However that only partially answers my problem as I wanted to have **multiple** proofing languages at the same time, not only one, French or English.  Is it possible? I know my phone can do it on Android, do Firefox can?

Comment: I added an extension in the ANS that can do it, try it out or This is an old thread, but there are some workarounds you can try https://superuser.com/questions/108177/how-do-i-make-firefox-spellcheck-in-multiple-languages-simultaneously#607039

Comment: Automatic Spelling Language extension is, honestly, the best thing ever! I don't get it, why Mozilla can't just inject this as the native feature instead of releasing "multilingual" spellcheck that does not work properly!